# Facebook app requests don't show message

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, notifications, request

I'm trying to deal with the Javascript Facebook API app request functionality.
I successfully log in with the FB.init method without asking for any extended permission. I'm perfectly able to fetch his profile picture, his friend list etc. But when it comes to sending app requests to my user's friends, I successfully display the dialog, actually SEND the notification, the notification is displayed on Facebook, but without the message!
I'm using FB.ui this way:

```
function sendRequest(to) {
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', to: to, message: 'You should learn more about this awesome site.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});
return false;
}
```

I tried with all sorts of messages, but no message is displayed, only "**Username** sent you a request". This happens both with users that didn't previously login with my app and with users that already authorized my app.
What should I do? Is there any way to display that message?

Thank you very much.

Matteo

Comment: Does the ordering matter in your 'FB.ui'? In the Facebook API on this I'm seeing message AFTER method and before to.